# heat equation with exponentially time dependent boundary condition

Tags: heat-equation

Consider the one dimensional heat equation on a semi-infinite bar such that

$u_t=u_{xx}$

with initial condition of

$u(x,0)=0$.

What is the solution for all x and t if the boundaries are

$u(0,t)=e^{-t}$
and
$u(x,t)=0$ as x approaches infinity?

Comment: You must take the 'Laplace Transform of your equation' but, in that way, it's not clear hot to handle "$\displaystyle\mathrm{u}\left(x,t\right) = 0$
 as x approaches infinity".